# Copy to clipboard with clip.exe

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

Running this gets the ip, subnet and gateway of a machine and saves it to the clipboard

However, the output is this:

```
IP Address: 
1.2.3.4
Subnet: 
255.255.255.0 
Gateway: 
1.2.3.4
```

Any way to get `$clipboard` to stop breaking each line?

```
IP Address: 10.63.89.219
Subnet: 255.255.255.224
Gateway: 10.63.89.222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it like this:

```
"IP Address: $ip","Subnet: $netMask","Gateway: $gateway" | C:\Windows\System32\clip.exe
```

Comment: Lol you're a godsend. I dont remember what I was doing but when I tried to put the $ in the quotes it was just putting "IP: $IP". Even though I didnt escape the $

Comment: @Techsupport323697 variable expansion in strings only work when you use double-quotes, ie. `"IP: $IP"` rather that `'IP: $IP'`

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a problem of `clip.exe` and more of wrong type declaration.

Example:

`$clipboard = "IP","$IP"`

- This creates an array with `$clipboard[0] = "IP"` and `$clipboard[1] = <value of $IP>`

But if you actually create an arry with the fields filled with the correct strings:

`$clipboard = "IP: $IP"`

- `$clipboard[0] = "IP: <value of $IP>"`

Note that the `,` will seperate the string objects and save each in a filed of the string-array.

So the solution to your problem would look like this instead:

```
"IP Address: $ip","Subnet: $netMask","Gateway: $gateway" | C:\Windows\System32\clip.exe
```

**Note that you don't have to save this into `$clipboard` since there will be no output after piping it to `clip.exe`, so `$clipboard` will be empty.**